# Subscript out of range error in R

Tags: r

I am new to R, and I encountered a strange error. I have table like this:

```
 dat<-c(1,2,3,4,4,53,62,345,3,4,346,23,34,52,34,2345,23,4)
 dat.table<-table(dat)
```

This creates a table and I would like to get a specific column from this table. When I try `dat.table[[3]]` it gives me 2 which is true occurrence of 3 in vector. But when I try `dat.table[[2345]]`, although 2345 is present in `rownames(dat.table)`, it gives the following error:

```
Error in b[[2345]] : subscript out of bounds
```

This is probably a basic question but its strange why R behaves differently for different rownames!!
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chance, the occurrence of "3" is stored in the 3rd column of `dat.table`.

Let's try with this example (2 zeros added):

```
dat <- c(0,1,2,3,4,4,53,62,345,3,4,346,23,34,0,52,34,2345,23,4)
dat.table[[3]]
[1] 1
```

Oops, wrong value. Now, let's try with

```
dat.table[["3"]]
[1] 2
```

Correct

"2345" is a character, the name of the column. When you type `dat.table[[2345]]`, you try to access the 2345th element, which doesn't exist. You need to specify the name of the column

```
dat <- c(1,2,3,4,4,53,62,345,3,4,346,23,34,52,34,2345,23,4)
dat.table <- table(dat)
dat.table[["2345"]]
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For accessing dat.table items:

```
dat.table['2345']
2345 
   1
```

dat.table is not a data.frame. Try following:

```
ddf = data.frame(dat.table)
ddf
    dat Freq
1     1    1
2     2    1
3     3    2
4     4    4
5    23    2
6    34    2
7    52    1
8    53    1
9    62    1
10  345    1
11  346    1
12 2345    1

 ddf[12,]
    dat Freq
12 2345    1

ddf[12,2]
[1] 1
```

ddf[[i]] gives column number i:

```
ddf[[1]]
 [1] 1    2    3    4    23   34   52   53   62   345  346  2345
Levels: 1 2 3 4 23 34 52 53 62 345 346 2345

ddf[[2]]
 [1] 1 1 2 4 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

For wide data.frame:

```
tt = data.frame(t(ddf))

tt
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11  X12
dat   1  2  3  4 23 34 52 53 62 345 346 2345
Freq  1  1  2  4  2  2  1  1  1   1   1    1
```